# Generating JSDocs from Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, jsdoc, parse-cloud-code, jsdoc3

I'm using Parse for a mobile app, I have a few Cloud Code functions and I want to generate documentation using JSDoc.

If I do this:

```
/** This is a Cloud Code function */
Parse.Cloud.define('foo', function(request, response){
});
```

JSDoc does not generate the documentation.

However, doing this works:

```
/** This is a javascript function */
function foo() {
}
```

Is it possible to document my Cloud Code functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution was pretty simple:

```
/** Document your Cloud Code function as a JS function */
var foo = function(request, response) {
}

//Then define it on Parse.Cloud
Parse.Cloud.define('foo', foo);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can also mark that using `@method` property:

```html
/** 
 * Document your Cloud Code function as a JS function 
 * @method foo
 */
Parse.Cloud.define('foo', function(request, response) {
  //...
});
```